# "pp. v. phrase" — Is this sentence pattern correct?

Tags: sentence-patterns

I get these kind of sentence structure too often from Czech people:

a `past participle`, followed by a `to be` verb, followed by the rest of the sentence.

For example, instead of saying

> The information is written here

I hear

> **Written here is the information**

It feels like there is a `what is` removed from the beginning of the sentence

> [What is] written here is the information

---

Another example:

> *[Secondary keys are useful for fast access by other fields than primary key.]* **Declared are as SecondaryKey.**

Instead of

> *[...]* They are declared as SecondaryKey

---

Or another example:

> **Enumerated are always all items**

instead of

> All items are always enumerated

---

Are these correct or incorrect in English?

Comment: Are these examples of real usage you've encountered?

Comment: @xiota yes, I hear the first one a lot, the two other examples are from a wiki page written by one of our experts

Comment: The first one seems fine to me. The other two are incomprehensible. Perhaps there's an underlying Czech structure they're trying to emulate.

Comment: The second two examples are very bizarre, even for Yoda. But while I can change the word order of the third example to make it normal, I can't even do that with the second example.

Comment: Highly inflected languages — Czech has 6 cases — can throw basically anything to the front. So can German with two fewer cases: _Gescheiben wurde das Buch von einem österreichischen Shriftsteller, der …_ Written was the book by an Austrian author who…

Comment: @KarlG English admits *Blessed is he who expects nothing, for never shall he be disappointed.* But that's less an illustration of declensional flexibility in word order than Latin's *Homo sum, nihil me alienum puto* or even  *Qui gladio ferit, gladio perit.*

Comment: When using the verb "to be" in any form, you can always transpose the subjects or transpose the subject and the predicate adjective, so you can say, "Written here is the information," just as properly as you can say, "The information is written here," and you can say, "Always enumerated are all items," just as properly as you can say, "All items are always enumerated."  I mean, when you put a predicate adjective first, you can come off as sounding like Yoda from Star Wars, but it's not improper, nor does it change the meaning.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman - I hope you will put this in an answer.  Perhaps add something about the missing subject in *Declared are as SecondaryKey* and the weird adverb placement in *Enumerated are always all items*.